# Qlik Sense Extension issue: TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, qliksense

I have created an extension that needs to use the Datatables plugin (https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/#Download). But when trying to initialize the plugin, according to the help:

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
```

I get an error message stating "TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function".

I know that jquery has been loaded, since I use it a lot in the extension without any issues.

**A minimal version of the Qlik Sense Extension javascript file:**

```
define( [
"qlik",
"jquery",
"text!./template.html",
"./datatables.min",
],
function ( qlik, $, template, datatables ) {

    return {
        template: template,
        support: {
            snapshot: true,
            export: true,
            exportData: false
        },
        paint: function () {
            var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();

            return qlik.Promise.resolve();
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ( $scope ) {
        }]
    };

} );
```

**template.html:**

```
<div qv-extension style="height: 100%; position: relative; overflow: auto;" class="ng-scope">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>     
    </table>
</div>
```

My guess is that i need to call the DataTable() in another way since datatables.min consists of anonymous functions and since Qlik Sense uses require.js to import external files.

You don't need to add extension .js when importing files through define([])

Comment: try adding the `.js` extension behind the `./js/datatables.min` giving `./js/datatables.min.js`

Comment: Adding `.js` to the module name won't solve your issue. Please reduce your code to a [mcve]. Otherwise, you'll only get guesses instead of answers.

Comment: You've edited your question, but you have not edited it into a **[mcve]**

Comment: @Louis This is as minfied as it gets when it comes to a Qlik Sense extension. But I have uploaded the minfied extension to https://ufile.io/ko327.

Comment: "Minimal" !== "minified", for one thing. You might want to look up what "minification" commonly means in JavaScript circles. However, there's the bigger issue that you're completely ignoring "complete" and "verifiable". And the MCVE must be in the body of the question, not stored on some other site.

Comment: @Louis You are absolutely correct. But when developing a Qlik Sense extension, what I gave you is a complete and verifiable solution. I am not really sure what else you need. Please let me know what else you need and I will try to fix that. But if you import the .zip that I linked into the QMC you have a complete solution ready.